# Extracting corresponding dataframe values from multiple records using a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df1) containing many records Each record has up to three trials, each trial can be repeat up to five times. Below is an example of some data I have:

```
Record   Trial   Start    End    Speed     Number
     1       2       1      4       12         9
     1       2       4      6       11        10
     1       3       1      3       10        17
     2       1       1      5       14         5
```

I have the following code that calculates the longest 'Distance' and 'Maximum Number' for each Record.:

```
getInfo <- function(race_df) {
  race_distance <- as.data.frame(race_df %>% group_by(record,trial) %>% summarise(max.distance = max(End - Start)))
  race_max_number = as.data.frame(race_df %>% group_by(record,trial) %>% summarise(max.N = max(Number)))
  rd_rmn_merge <- as.data.frame(merge(x = race_distance, y = race_max_number)
  total_summary <- as.data.frame(rd_rmn_merge[order(rd_rmn_merge$trial,])
  return(list(race_distance, race_max_number, total_summary)
}

list_summary <- getInfo(race_df)
total_summary <- list_of_races[[3]]
```

`list_summary` gives me an output like this:

```
 [[1]]
 Record   Trial    Max.Distance  
      1       2       3       
      1       3       2     
      2       1       4      

 [[2]]
 Record    Trial    Max.Number
      1       2       10
      1       3       17
      2       1        5

 [[3]]
 Record  Trial    Max.Distance    Max.Number 
      1       2        3             10
      1       3        2             17
      2       1        4              5
```

I am now trying to seek the longest distance with the corresponding 'Number' regardless if it being maximum. So having Record 1, Trial 2 look like this instead:

```
Record   Trial     Max.Distance  Corresponding Number
     1       2          3                9
```

Eventually I would like to be able to create a function that is able to take arguments 'Record' and 'Trial' through the 'race_df' dataframe to make searching for a specific record and trial's longest distance easier.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data (in case anyone else wants to offer their solution):

```
df <- data.frame( Record = c(1,1,1,2),
                  Trial = c(2,2,3,1),
                  Start = c(1,4,1,1),
                  End = c(4,6,3,5),
                  Speed = c(12,11,10,14),
                  Number = c(9,10,17,5))
```

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate( Max.Distance = End - Start) %>% 
  select(-Start,-End,-Speed) %>%
  group_by(Record) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate( data = map( data, ~ filter(.x, Max.Distance == max(Max.Distance)) )) %>% 
  unnest()
```

The output:

```
  Record Trial Number Max.Distance
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1     2      9            3
2      2     1      5            4
```

Note if you want to keep all of your columns in the final data frame, just remove `select...`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding :) I tried implementing this code, however, I received this error:
`Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’`
So I did a bit of searching and used this code to install it
`install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source")` and it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 2):

I hope I get right what your function is supposed to do. In the end it should take a record and a trial and put out the row(s) where we have the maximum distance, right? 
So, it boils down to two filters:

1. filter rows for the record and trial.
2. filter the row inside that subset that has the maximum distance

Between those two filters, we have to calculate the distance although I suggest you move that outside the function because it is basically a one time operation.

```
race_df <- data.frame(Record = c(1, 1, 1, 2), Trial = c(2, 2, 3, 1),
                 Start = c(1, 4, 1, 1), End = c(4, 6, 3, 5), Speed = c(12, 11, 10, 14),
                 Number = c(9, 10, 17, 5))

get_longest <- function(df, record, trial){
  df %>% 
    filter(Record == record & Trial == trial) %>% 
    mutate(Distance = End - Start) %>% 
    filter(Distance == max(Distance)) %>%
    select(Number, Distance)
}
get_longest(race_df, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I'm just wanting Distance and Number. How would I remove Start, End and Speed to the output?

Comment: see my edit. If that solves your problem, you could accept my answer. Ps: I suggest you have a look at the [data transformation chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) of Hadley Wickham's free ebook "R for Data Science". dplyr is very powerful!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and edit! I tried implementing the code with select but received back this error:

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’ `

Not entirely sure what that means and now looking for examples on the internet.

Comment: After using `install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source")`. It now works, thanks very much.